# How to check app target API as an SDK for Android

Tags: android

So we are an SDK and is looking to implement Notification channels, and we use NotificationCompat.Builder which is from a support library, which would need to have 26.0.1 of appcompat to make use of the new channels based constructor.

But some of our users may not actually target 26.0.1 build tools / libraries (IE 25.4.0), and may compile with 25.0.3 build tools (or even older). We found that with us using the standard Build.VERSION.SDK_INT gate we still get app crash on Oreo devices that is related to using the newer function when in theory since the app is targeting API 25 and below and the code should not be running in that mode (IE android should be in compatibility mode and thus no need for channels).

Anyone know a better way to gate the usage of these kind of APIs with what the TARGET API is when the app is targeting older devices we should then use the older non channel implementation. As when the app is targeting an older version and thus we should get older behavior. I mean we can spec to use 26.0.1, but they may just force conflict resolution, which compiles the code into apk and installs on Oreo, then just simply crashes with a NoSuchMethodError when notifications comes.